# Matlab: can not simplify a symbolic scalar function use subs() in a simple case

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

It is just a simple case in matlab, something strange about function subs() happens and I don't know why.

I have read the official help doc and googled the error message but didn't find useful information.

Could someone tell me what wrong the the command "subs(f)"?

```
>> syms x w b f
>> f=x*w-b
f =
w*x - b
>> w=[1 2 3 ;4 5 6; 7 8 9 ]
w =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
>> x=[1 2 3.44]'
x =
    1.0000
    2.0000
    3.4400
>> b=[ 2 4 7 ]'
b =
     2
     4
     7
>> f
f =
w*x - b
>> subs(f)
Error using symengine
New arrays must have the same dimensions or must be scalars.
Error in sym/subs>mupadsubs (line 140)
G = mupadmex('symobj::fullsubs',F.s,X2,Y2);
Error in sym/subs (line 125)
    G = mupadsubs(F,X,Y);
```

here is a screenshot of the error message:
[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am waiting online for the answer, emmm…… please help :)

Comment: The answer lies in the subtleties of how `subs` replaces scalars with arrays.  Before I attempt to answer the question in a coherent manner, why are you using Symbolic variables to begin with?  You will get far, far better performance using `double` and similar behavior with an anonymous function like `f = @(w,x,b) w*x - b;`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I use symbolic variable because I may want the deravative of x for some other purpose, can use an anonymous function and  double variables to do that?

Comment: That depends entirely on your intended uses.  But if I remember correctly, the Jacobian of a linear system is just the coefficient matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Symbolic Toolbox operates from the standpoint that Symbolic Variables are scalars and any operation or expression in which they are present uses element-wise semantics.  As states in the [`subs` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html#btqh2ho-1):

> If `old` is a scalar, and `new` is a vector or matrix, then `subs(s,old,new)` replaces all instances of `old` in `s` with `new`, performing all operations elementwise. All constant terms in `s` are replaced with the constant times a vector or matrix of all 1s.

So the expression undergoing substitution needs to play nice with element-wise application and expansion upon substitution.  However, when the new arrays being substituted do no match size in every dimension (as is the case here with the coefficient matrix being rectangular versus the column vector), a dimension mismatch will more than likely occur in the engine.  Even direct specification of the substitution with cell arrays throws the error:

```
>> wnum = [1 2 3 ;4 5 6; 7 8 9 ];
>> xnum = [1 2 3.44]';
>> bnum = [ 2 4 7 ]';
>> subs(f,{w,x,b},{wnum,xnum,bnum})
Error using symengine
New arrays must have the same dimensions or must be scalars.

Error in sym/subs>mupadsubs (line 140)
G = mupadmex('symobj::fullsubs',F.s,X2,Y2);

Error in sym/subs (line 125)
    G = mupadsubs(F,X,Y);
```

While fully conforming dimensional substitutions will work just fine:

```
>> subs(f,{w,x,b},{xnum,xnum,xnum}); % All 3x1
>> subs(f,{w,x,b},{wnum,wnum,wnum}); % All 3x3
```

And all of this derives from the Symbolic Variables themselves being treated as scalars.  The Symbolic work-around being to declare the variables as Symbolic Arrays to generate the individual elements of the arrays and allow for a one-to-one substitution:

```
>> w = sym('w',[3,3]);
>> x = sym('x',[3,1]);
>> b = sym('b',[3,1]);
>> f = w*x - b;
>> subs(f,[w,x,b],[wnum,xnum,bnum])

ans =

  333/25
  766/25
 1174/25
```

---

Of course, the best course of action, if you can do so, is to avoid the Symbolic Toolbox entirely or as much as possible.

```
>> double(subs(f,[w,x,b],[wnum,xnum,bnum]))
ans =
   13.3200
   30.6400
   46.9600

>> fnum = wnum*xnum - bnum
fnum =
   13.3200
   30.6400
   46.9600
```

The above discussion is a very, very large reason as to why I leave Linear Algebra to the MATLAB run-time proper, aside from all of the performance increases associated with it.  The Symbolic Toolbox, in my opinion, is best left to analysis of functions in one or more variables (I use it to create Taylor Series, Jacobians, and Hessians often enough) or high precision analysis of a small dimensional problem for investigative purposes.